# how to "bundle" two javascript functions into one, when only the selector and function to call vary?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, optimization

I have the following function callers in a snippet:

```
// del
if ( maxDelivery > 0 ) {
    if ( maxDelivery === 1 ){
        delAdressFunc( dels );
    } else {
        for ( i = 0; i < maxDelivery; i += 1 ){
            delAdressFunc( dels[i] );
        }
    }
}

// ajax
if ( maxAjaxTables > 0 ){
    if ( maxAjaxTables === 1 ){
        getAjaxTable( ajx, 0 );   
    } else {
        for ( j = 1; j <= maxAjaxTables; j += 1){
            getAjaxTable( ajx[j-1], j )
        }
    }
}
```

So the setup is pretty much the same for both function calls.

**Question:**
Is there a way to combine both into a single "caller" to save some duplicate code?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:
Sorry for omitting... `dels` and `ajx` are both element selectors, which I'm constructing like so:

```
dels = $('.selectDeliveryAdress').filter(function() { return $(this).jqmData("bound") !== true; });
maxDelivery = dels.length;
```

I need to make sure the function only gets called once on each element, so I'm filtering for `jqmData("bound")` and setting it to true in `delAdressFunc()`.

So it will either be 0, 1 (most likely) or 2+ elements. Same for `ajx` and `maxAjaxTables` (= ajx.length )

Comment: Just pass the variables that vary (e.g. `maxAjaxTables`, `ajx`, `getAjaxTable`) as arguments to a function. This question is a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ IMO.

Comment: It's a little bit more complicated here because the amount of arguments vary. But you can use `.apply` for this (or have `delAddressFunc` accept the index as well). Also it's cleaner to have your second loop run from `0` and remove the `-1`.

Comment: How is the `dels` variable set? (Why is it sometimes an array and sometimes not?) Same question for `ajx`... You can remove the `if ( maxDelivery > 0 ) {` test, because (without it) if `maxDelivery` is `0` it will go to the `for` statement and do nothing.

Comment: So `dels` is either a certain type of object, or an array of such objects? It would be easier to work with if it always were an array.

Comment: editing. See above (in 1 minute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function caller(obj, max, func) {
    if ( max > 0 ) {
        if ( max === 1 ){
            func( obj );
        } else {
            for ( i = 0; i < max; i += 1 ) {
                func( obj[i] );
            }
        }
    }
}

caller(dels, maxDelivery, delAdressFunc);
caller(ajx, maxAjaxTables, getAjaxTable);
```